# What is the physical significance of taking derivative with respect to proper time?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time, velocity

I would like to know if there is any physical significance associated with the derivative of a quantity with respect to proper time or is it just a mathematical trick. Since proper time is measured in its "rest" frame of a moving particle, it seems to me that particle is not going through any dynamics and therefore time derivatives should be zero in the rest frame. I understand that we use derivatives with respect to proper time to keep things Lorentz invariant....but that sounds more like a mathematical requirement rather than something of physical significance. Example: what is the physical significance of four-velocity. I know four velocity is tangent to the worldline but I find it hard to remember through physical intuition. I always have to go through a book to find its definition.

Kindly excuse my ignorance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derivative with respect to proper time is the derivative with respect to time of the instantaneously comoving inertial frame.

This does **not** mean the particle is at rest. That's why I had to have the word *instantaneously* in there.

As for four velocity, that's the unit tangent vector to the world line. It tells you what direction in spacetime something is going.

Just like a unit velocity vector tells you the direction a particle is going in Newtonian mechanics.